# Using str_replace to wrap content?

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
user.0.name
```

I wish to replace each dot with square bracket, but also close the square bracket at the next dot or the end of string. It would become something like:

```
user[0][name]
```

I've tried:

```
str_replace('.', '[', 'user.0.name');
```

But how do you maintain the content after each dot and place a closing square bracket after the content?

Comment: Also, you should specify whether you'll always have that exact format or if more dots can be expected, and how they should be treated in that case.

Comment: do you want to output in a string format???

if yes then please check it

   $str="user.0.name";
        $arr= explode(".", $str);
      
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key==0){
        $lstr=$value;
    }else{
       $lstr.="[".$value."]";
    }
    
}echo $lstr;

Comment: `preg_replace("(.([0-9]+).([A-Za-z]+))", "[$1][$2]", $string);` works for me. See it running here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5b034cbcaa6d1535a25f1e8d35d6539fb2a4202

Comment: `preg_replace ('/\\.([^.]+)/', '[\\1]', $str)` -- this one should accept any other string as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `str_replace`, but simply loop over all characters - and if it is a dot, replace it with either `'['` or `']'`, alternating between the two:

```
$str = 'user.0.name.1.foobar';

$bracket = '[';

for($i=0, $l=strlen($str); $i<$l; ++$i) {
  if($str[$i] == '.') {
   $str[$i] = $bracket;
   $bracket = $bracket == '[' ? ']' : '[';
  }
}

echo $str; // result: user[0]name[1]foobar
```

Edit:

Just seeing this might not be what you want, since now you are saying it should be `user[0][name]`- but that’s not what you initially asked for, *“I wish to replace each dot with square bracket”* …

Here’s a version that should be able to do that:

```
$str = 'user.0.name.1.foobar';
$output = '';

$bracket = '[';

for($i=0, $l=strlen($str); $i<$l; ++$i) {
  if($str[$i] == '.') {
   $output .= $bracket;
   $bracket = '][';
  }
  else {
    $output .= $str[$i];
  }
}
$output .= ']';
echo $output; // Result: user[0][name][1][foobar]
```

Comment: A third alternative if you want one (as no more answers can be added) `$input = 'user.0.name';
$parts = explode(".", $input);
$output = array_shift($parts)."[".implode("][", $parts)."]";`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $str = "user.0.name";
 $arr = explode(".",$str);
 $newArr = [];
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key != 0)
         $value = '[' .$value.']';
    array_push($newArr, $value);
 }
 $newStr = implode("",$newArr);
 echo $newStr;
```